# In QuickBlox Chat, How to get userList by some cusom filter

Tags: android, chat, quickblox

In ChatService class there is a call:

```
QBUsers.getUsersByIDs(usersIDs, requestBuilder, new QBEntityCallbackImpl<ArrayList<QBUser>>()
```

What if I want user list by some other filter. There **is** a option of getting user by some filter.

```
public static QBRequestCanceler getUsersByFilter(Collection<?> filterValue, String filter, QBPagedRequestBuilder requestBuilder, QBEntityCallback<ArrayList<QBUser>> callback)
```

But how to use that.

Example If I have a database where one USER is Related with other USER by some relation. How should I retrieve a user list that satisfies that relation.

Comment: Question should be specific.

Comment: What more specification are needed?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example , it would make a good starting point on usage:

```
 ArrayList<String> userId = new ArrayList();
 userId.add("4200005");
 QBUsers.getUsersByFilter(userId,"number id ne ", getQBPagedRequestBuilder(currentPage), this);
```

Where **userId** is the current user id *(mine was 4200005)*.

The **"number id ne "** can be interchanged with any of these filters http://quickblox.com/developers/Users#Filters